# How do I call a function with a variable in Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I've looked over the web, I haven't really found an answer. I have the following code:

```
@echo off
set Xval=1
set Yval=1
call :%Xval% 2>nul
pause
exit /b

:%Yval%
echo I have been called
pause
exit /b
```

It's supposed to call the function of %Xval%, which equals "1".

I have another variable, which also equals 1. It is %Yval%, and it is named as the function.

Therefore, I thought that by calling %Xval% (which equals 1), it would call :%Yval%, as it should be equal to :1.

Why doesn't this work? And is there a solution? Thank you :)

Comment: `%random%` is a system variable. Try using something else.

Comment: Ah okay. I changed it to Yval instead

Comment: Your labels cannot be variables.  When you call a label with in your batch file it physically starts at the top of the batch file and tries to find the literal text of the label.  In this case it is trying to find `:1` in your batch file.  That does not exist. When a line of code is executed the variables on that line are expanded to their value.  Your %Yval% variable is not expanded because it is on a separate line.

Comment: Batch has no functions - just callable subroutines. A function can return something - the only thing batch subs can return is an errorlevel via the exit command.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
set Xval=1
set Yval=1
call :%%%%Xval%%%% 2>nul
pause
exit /b

:%Xval%
echo I have been called
pause
exit /b
```

When you `call` or `goto` a label, the interpreter pauses execution, reads the file to the end to find the **literal** label. If not found, will read from start of file to the end. If not found, errors with cannot find the label. If found, continues execution from the found label.

Looking for label `:%Yval%` can be done with escaping the percentage signs of the **runtime** code i.e. `call :%%%%Yval%%%%`.

Comment: This does work - but not in the sense OP intended. Your doubled escaping takes the label as literal `%Xval%` Didn't know that such a label is possible. To see **what** is called insert `%0` into the echo (+1)